# Why is $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{itx}\frac{1}{\pi(1+x^2)}dx=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(y^2+ \frac{t^2}{y^2}\right)}dy$?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, fourier-analysis

I understand that there are two ways of representing $e^{-|t|}$:

$$
e^{-|t|} = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(y^2+ \frac{t^2}{y^2}\right)}dy 
$$

and also that

$$
e^{-|t|} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{itx}\frac{1}{\pi(1+x^2)}dx
$$

However, I cannot reconcile or see why these two are necessarily equal. Is there a way to see why these two are necessarily equal without resorting to just pure mechanics? Thanks.

Comment: I do not understand your question: if you are able to prove that both integrals equal $e^{-|t|}$, what else do you need? An equality follows from a Fourier transform and the other one by Glasser's master theorem.

Comment: Note that there are not just two ways of representing this function as an integral - there are infintely many different ways that are not neccessarily easily related. Usually the easiest way to show such an equivalence is to simply show that each representation equals the function that trying to find a smart transformation from one to the other.

Comment: If I might ask, how is the first integral solved?

Comment: By using that the integrand is even and completing the square the first integral can be written $$e^{-|t|}\sqrt{\frac{1}{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(y - \frac{|t|}{y}\right)^2}\,{\rm d}y$$
This integral is on the form $\int_{-\infty}^\infty F(\phi(y))\,{\rm d}y$ with $\phi(y) = y - \frac{|t|}{y}$ which allows us to apply [Glasser's Master Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GlassersMasterTheorem.html) to get that it's equal to the gaussian integral $e^{-|t|}\sqrt{\frac{1}{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{1}{2}y^2}\,{\rm d}y = e^{-|t|}$